# OpenGl и ввод значений

Tags: c++, opengl

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста.

Пользователь должен ввести значения и по ним должен построиться полигон.
Нужно ввести 9 точек для его построения.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ptlist.h"
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>



void showStructure();
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE |  GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutCreateWindow("PointList");
    glutDisplayFunc(showStructure);

    glutMainLoop();
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

void showStructure()
{


    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    GLfloat first(0.2);
    GLfloat second(0.1);
    GLfloat third(-0.5);

        std::cout << "Point 1: ";
        std::cin >> first;
        std::cout << "Point 2: ";
        std::cin >> second;
        std::cout << "Point 3: ";
        std::cin >> third;


        glVertex3f(GLfloat(first), GLfloat(second), GLfloat(third));
        glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.0f, -0.5f); 
        glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f); 

    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Проблема в том , что если я делаю так:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

GLfloat first(0.2);
GLfloat second(0.1);
GLfloat third(-0.5);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{ 
        std::cout << "Point 1: ";
        std::cin >> first;
        std::cout << "Point 2: ";
        std::cin >> second;
        std::cout << "Point 3: ";
        std::cin >> third;
    glVertex3f(GLfloat(first), GLfloat(second), GLfloat(third));
}
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
```

То цикл уходит в бесконечность и полигон не рисуется.

В случае таком, полигон рисуется после ввода трех точек, но в ожидании ввода дальше(т.е. цикл тоже в бесконечность):

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    GLfloat first(0.2);
    GLfloat second(0.1);
    GLfloat third(-0.5);


        std::cout << "Point 1: ";
        std::cin >> first;
        std::cout << "Point 2: ";
        std::cin >> second;
        std::cout << "Point 3: ";
        std::cin >> third;


        glVertex3f(GLfloat(first), GLfloat(second), GLfloat(third));
        glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.0f, -0.5f); // Bottom Left
        glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Bottom Left*/

    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
```

Подскажите , пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать ввод данных?

Comment: А какие Вы данные вводите? Приведите конкретный пример пожалуйста.

Comment: @RomanPodymov ввожу вещественные цифры , например: 0.5 , 1.0, -0.5

Comment: Может стоит реализовать ввод данных в `main` до `glutInit(&argc, argv);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш цикл вызывается бесконечно, т.к. функция showStructure вызывается для каждой отрисовки. А при 30 fps это раз в 1000/30 = 33 мсек. Судя по всему вам необходимо прочитать параметры полигона один раз и рисовать его не предлагая пользователю вводить информацию. Ввод можно организовать вот так:

```
const int pointsNumber = 9;
float points[pointsNumber];
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pointsNumber; i++)
    { 
        std::cout << "Point " << pointsNumber << ": ";
        std::cin >> points[i];
    }
```

...

А рисовать используя данные из points.